# Can not import packages at plugin.xml from jars which are loaded as maven dependency?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I would like to take advantage of the features that Maven provides for managing dependencies in a project. My brief understanding of how Maven works is that it will aquire the JARs needed and then build the project with these libraries. So i have installed and configured maven on my computer. Also i have installed the me2eclipse plugin version 0.12 on my eclipse helios.

I have been created a maven project and configured the pom. I added some dependencies to maven and maven was checking out the dependend jars to %userprofile%/.me2/repository. This works fine. But i would like to import some packages from the jar files which are located at the maven dependencies at my plugin.xml which are used by running a eclipse rcp plugin. The maven dependencies are added to my classpath as well.

I don't know were the mistake is? Can any body help my. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, thats not possible to import some packages from jars or bundles which are loaded as maven dependency (stored at the maven local repositiry) at the eclipse rcp plugin dependency or MANIFEST. You can only import bundles or packages from jars which are located at the eclipse target platform. So the solution is to add the bundles which ar located at the local maven repository to the target platform as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a deep look at [Maven-Felix](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) which supports you in this kind of building. Furthermore i recommend you to update to Eclipse-Indigo and use the integrated (Marketplace) m2e instead of the old m2eclipse plugin.